# OJS: Lock the whole System / any article creation functionality

Tags: ojs

I use the Command line Tools NativeImportExportPlugin to programmatically mass import articles into the OJS. While doing this, I have to know the IDs the new articles will get before they are imported, for example to print the URL in the PDF. Unfortunately these IDs are generated by AUTO_INCREMENT and are no UUIDs. I can anticipate them safely by asking the the DB for the last used ID, but this could become unsafe if some other user would upload some data to the OJS at the very same time.
I would appreciate if I could prevent other users to upload anything while the mass import is ongoing.

So my question: **Is there any (not overly complicated way) to lock and later unlock the whole OJS or any article creation functionality?**

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using custom identifiers; these can be enabled in setup, and will replace the auto-generated IDs in URLs when they're provided.

Comment: Thank you Alec, meanwhile I came to the same solution.